# cocos2dx v3.0 Sprite with texture from URL cross platform (iOS & Android)

Tags: android, ios, url, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i’m working on an cross platform app (iOS, Android) with cocos2dx v3.0. I want to create a CCSprite with a texture from an URL. I think there is no cocos-way to do this, so I have to fork my code for Android and iOS. The iOS part isn’t a problem, but how can I download an image on Android and use it as texture for a CCSprite?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think you download the image just like in any other context than use said image in the sprite.  What are you having trouble with?